# Find indexes that form the Middle point of a Non-decreasing and Non-increasing sequence

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Given a list of positive integers and an integer `k`.

Find all indexes `r` in the list such that the `k` numbers before the index `r` and including the number at index `r` form a non-increasing `r` and including the number at index `r` forms a non-decreasing sequence.

*Example*:

```
list =  [3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4] and k = 2 output = [2,3]
```

**My Thoughts:**

One naive approach would be for each index to check the `k` elements in front of it and the `k` elements behind it. Not sure if there could be some efficient way to do it.

An alternative would be to scan the list, and if two consecutive number `a` and `b` are found such that `a<b` then  from this index till the next `k` index, none of the indexes could be in the output.

I am looking for an efficient approach. Coding I could do myself.

Answer (score 0):

A sliding window approach would work here. In essence you are looking for the middle of valleys of length `2*k+1`. This can be done in linear time with a space complexity of `k`.

Here are the general steps to achieve this:

1. Use a doubly ended queue for the window to get constant addition/removal time from both ends and also constant access time by index.
2. Start iterating over the input array for `k+1` elements and add them to the deq while they are none-increasing. If you find some violation, reset the deq to the index after the violation as you can be sure that you won't find the first part (none-increasing) before that index.
3. If/when you get your `k+1` non-increasing elements, save the index your current potential valley as `r`. start to add the remaining `k` elements, this time the condition is to be non-decreasing. Now, here are 3 possibilities:

a. The element is non-decreasing: Add it to the deq.

b. The element is decreasing: This is a violation with 2 possibilities:

b1. You already had some increasing elements before: This means that you can't use the part before this for the number 2 (non-increasing). In this case, you just have to let go of all you got till here and start from your current index+1 with step 2. The first part.

b2. You didn't have any increasing elements, this means that the first part is still good. You can move `r` to the current index and be sure that all the elements from `r-k` to `r` are non-increasing. Now, go to step 3, trying to find the non-decreasing part.

4. Now suppose you find a window of size `2*k+1`. Store `r` in your results and start moving the window forward by removing an element from the head of the deque and adding one to the tail. Check whether the new `r` is still a valley by making sure `r-1 <= r` and `r+1 >= r`. Also check whether the newly added element to the deq is non-decreasing. If so, you're all good. Store the new `r` in your result.